# Hysteresis curve for ferromagnet different types?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If you type 'hysteresis curve for ferromagnetic' in to google you get several different types. Looking at the once with $B$ against $H$ there are some that appear to go flat at satruation: 
[image]

And those that appear to tend towards a straight line (which I guess is the line $H=B$):

[image]

Are both these curves right in different situations (if so what situations?) or is one wrong, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0210657.pdf the 2nd graph is correct while the 1st isn't. The 1st graph, where a saturation for $\vec B$ is shown, is apparently a misconception that many authors had/have. The correct graph with a saturation would be $H$ vs $M$, i.e. the ferromagnetic/ferrimagnetic sample have a maximum magnetization that can't be increased (or only 3 orders of magnitude slower), the so-called saturation.

I think that you're right to think that eventually (for large values of H), B is approximately worth H. That's because $\vec B=\mu _0 (\vec H + \vec M )$ and $\vec M$ will eventually reach a saturation value from which it won't increase anymore or almost, while both $\vec H$ and $\vec B$ can increase. So that for $\vec H >> \vec M_\text{saturation}$, $\vec B \approx \mu_0 \vec H$ holds. Where I used the SI for units. In CGS units the $\mu_0$ constant does not appear. Hence the 2nd graph is the correct one, assuming a B vs H plot.